# ERROR: google-colab 1.0.0 has requirement google-auth~=1.17.2, but you'll have google-auth 1.22.0 which is incompatible

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-cloud-vision

*Suddenly colab shows this error while installing cloud vision and using the api.How to solve this issue?How to update google-auth in colab?*

```
!pip install google-cloud-vision
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_file(
"/content/gdrive/My Drive/dataset/test3-4a6f8fdcb08c.json"
)
```

`ERROR: google-colab 1.0.0 has requirement google-auth~=1.17.2, but you'll have google-auth 1.22.0 which is incompatible`

```
ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d300b7f6306a> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install google-cloud-vision')
----> 2 from google.cloud import vision
      3 from google.cloud.vision import types
      4 
      5 client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient.from_service_account_file(

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    773                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    774                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 775                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    776 
    777             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (google-api-core 1.16.0 (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.22.2'), {'google-cloud-vision'})
```

Comment: I have the same issue with dialogflow libraries trying to run on colab

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem importing pubsub from `google.cloud` library on Colabs. I just restart the runtime and the same code runs without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just reload your colab.ipynb page and should be fine